# How To Selectively Load External Images Using Htacess

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, redirect

I want to load all the pictures except 3 ones from external site by certain rule. The remaining 3 should be loaded from default image.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !image_1.jpg$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !image_2.jpg$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !image_3.jpg$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://external-site.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Else - if  {REQUEST_URI} contains image_1.jpg or image_2.jpg or image_1.jpg then load image from lets say http://mydomain.com/default_image.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(image_1|image_2|image_3)\.jpg   [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) http://external-site.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (image_1|image_2|image_3)\.jpg [NC]
RewriteRule .*             /default_image.jpg        [R=301,L]
```